# How to Run SSH on remote machine and leave?

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, ssh

I want to achieve the following scenarios:

1. Connect to remote machine via SSH
2. Run command on remote machine - that usually takes 3 days to complete and shows output while working
3. Leave the SSH connection without killing that command terminal process
4. Connect to remote machine from other machine and see the running output of command.

Comment: 1st thing that comes to mind is a detached Screen. Am I understanding?

Comment: @EODCraftStaff can we detach screen from one console and connect the screen from other machine ?

Comment: @Jos "Connect to remote machine from other machine and see the running output of command." - do you think its possible?

Comment: In the first session, you would need to redirect STDOUT output to a file. In the next session, you would do `tail -f filename` to see the running output.

Comment: @Jos can you post an example for this so i can see. the process will be constantly writing output to console that runs via ssh

Answer (score 1):

First session:

```
command >> logfile &
```

Executes `command` in the background and redirects STDOUT output to a file. Watch the output:

```
tail -f logfile
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to stop viewing the output (not the process itself).

Detach the process from the current session and exit:

```
disown
exit
```

Second session:

See the current output of the (still running) process:

```
tail -f logfile
```

Comment: actually i want to shutdown the host computer from which i started the SSH command on VM and connect to same VM command line instance from other machine ? Will this answer work on other machine?